# Raw data before each group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by, rollup

Which queries should I execute in order to show raw data before every group by row? Is there a way to do that?

```
User   ReceiptNo   Price
-----  ----------  ------
A      876         100
A      877          50
                   **150**
B      960          60
B      961          40
                   **100**
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Do you want this to be done using a SQL or you prefer doing this sub totals & grand totals in a reporting tools such as Tableau or SSRS? You should research about using ROLLUP in SQL. That should help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most database support standard group by modifiers such as `rollup` or `grouping sets`.  If so, you can do:

```
select user, receiptno, sum(price) as price
from t
group by grouping sets ((user, receiptno), (user));
```

Comment: This works fine on my machine with Sql Server 2014 but on SQL Server 2008 throws error   Incorrect syntax near 'sets'.

Comment: @kk_nou . . . I'm fairly sure SQL Server 2008 supports this syntax (for instance, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2007/10/11/grouping-sets-in-sql-server-2008/).  Perhaps you have a compatibility setting on that server set to an earlier version.

Answer (score 0):

```
select user, receiptno, price, 1 as order_column 
from t
union all
select user, '' as receiptno, sum(price) as price, 2 as order_column 
from t
group by user

order by user, order_column
```

You can union results with raw data and add an artificial column to be used in ORDER BY to place the aggregate rows in the end of groups (after raw data).